# Dataset API for TensorFlow : Variable sized Input

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

I have my entire dataset in memory as list of tuples where each tuple corresponds to a batch of fixed size 'N' . i.e

(x[i],label[i],length[i])

- x[i]: numpy array of shape [N,W,F]; here there are N examples, with W timestep each; all timesteps have fixed number of features F
- label[i] : class:  shape [N,] one for each example in batch
- length[i] : length (number of timesteps ) in data : shape [N,] : this is number of timesteps (W) for each example in batch

**Main problem : Across the batches W varies .**

I was looking at the following [examples](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/tutorials/image/cifar10/cifar10_multi_gpu_train.py) and [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.3/programmers_guide/datasets) for Dataset API but could not understand how to create a DataSet object for my case. API's like Dataset.from_tensor_slices and Dataset.from_tensor don't seem to be working (throwing broadcasting errors) as they require tensors to be of same shape i,e W across batches to be the same. Is there any way I can do without having to pad my batches (using DataSet.padded_batch) ?

Comment: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/13018#issuecomment-329287100 seems to be the solution

Comment: How do you use DataSet.padded_batch to read your structure? I have a similar partial dynamic structure and want to use Dataset API to read it (and return a list of [x, label, length]). Setting `padded_shapes=[None]` returns the error: `TypeError: If shallow structure is a sequence, input must also be a sequence. Input has type: <class 'list'>.`

Comment: I figured out how to set the `padded_shapes` now (see my other post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46531137/8179854). I'm curious how to use `from_generator` to solve this variable-length padding problem?

Comment: Just need to copy the from_generator function (along with the subclass) from 1..4 to 1.3 (same location)

Comment: @MaosiChen to use `tf.data.Dataset.from_generator`, you first need to create a callable generator such as `def callable_generator(): yield [(i, i * i) for i in range(N)]` and then pass it to the `from_generator` function together with a type. However, it may not help with your problem as it also expects stackable (equi-dimensional) tensors as mini-batches. It didn't work for me when `N` was varied across mini-batches, so I don't expect it to work when any of the other dimensions are varied either.